# Closing PHP tag to stop link appearing in unwanted place (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

The last link here (https://soundcloud.com/waxworkfigurine2) is attached to my 'featured header text' header. Am I not closing the php tag properly?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if(of_get_option('show_infoboxes') == true) { ?>
    <div class="promo">
        <section class=" block grid4">
            <div class="col">
                <?php if(of_get_option('infobox_image_1')) { ?> <a href='http://www.facebook.com/waxworkfigurine'><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_1') ?>"</a> <?php } ?>
                <?php echo of_get_option('infobox_text_1') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <?php if(of_get_option('infobox_image_2')) { ?> <a href='https://twitter.com/waxworkfigurine'><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_2') ?>" alt=""</a> <?php } ?>
                <?php echo of_get_option('infobox_text_2') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <?php if(of_get_option('infobox_image_3')) { ?> <a href='https://soundcloud.com/waxworkfigurine'><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_3') ?>" alt=""</a> <?php } ?>
                <?php echo of_get_option('infobox_text_3') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <?php if(of_get_option('infobox_image_4')) { ?> <a href='https://soundcloud.com/waxworkfigurine2'><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_4') ?>" alt=""</a> <?php } ?>
                <?php echo of_get_option('infobox_text_4') ?>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <?php  } ?>

    <section class="featured block grid2">

        <h2><?php echo of_get_option('featured_header_text') ?></h2>
```

Comment: what is the content of `featured_header_text` ?

Comment: A text header, 'News'

Comment: What is the expected result, and what do you get infact ?

Comment: Expected result just the text News - actual result = text News with a hyperlink to http://soundcloud.com/waxworkfigurine2

Comment: All of your image tags are missing a closing `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing tag for the img, add `/>` before `</a>`

```
 <div class="col">
     <?php if(of_get_option('infobox_image_4')) { ?> 
         <a href='https://soundcloud.com/waxworkfigurine2'>
             <img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_4') ?>" alt="" />
         </a> 
     <?php } ?>
     <?php echo of_get_option('infobox_text_4') ?>
</div>
```

Proper code spacing can save you lots of small erros like this, it takes a bit more space but is clearer and easier to read.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you see something wrong in my post please comment it, there is no value in just down-voting...

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly close `<img>` tags:

```
<img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_3') ?>" alt=""></a>
                                                                ^-----
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to terminate all of your lines with a semi-colon - e.g.

```
    <h2><?php echo of_get_option('featured_header_text'); ?></h2>
```

Also I find it easier to go:

```
<?php if(of_get_option('infobox_image_4')) : ?> <a href='https://soundcloud.com/waxworkfigurine2'><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('infobox_image_4'); ?>" alt="" /></a> <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: semi-colon is not required if there is single operation.

Comment: Changed need to 'should' - it's good practice to do this regardless.  Also noted that you're missing closing your image tag so added this too.

Comment: Brill, it's really easy to miss bits and bobs like that :)